# CIContext initialization crash

Tags: ios, image, camera, swift2

**Background:**
I'm running a swift 2 application with the following two options.

*Option A:*
The user can enter a number to sign in. In this case, his/her picture is shown in a UIImageView.

*Option B:*
The user can use an NFC tag to sign in. In this case, the UIImageView is replaced with a camera layer that shows live camera stream and uses CIContext to capture an image on a button press.

**Problem:**
The issue I'm facing is that sometimes, when I choose option A (not using the camera layer), the app crashes. Since I'm unable to reproduce the crash deterministically, I have hit a dead end to understand why the app is crashing.

**EDIT:** The camera layer is used in both options but is hidden in option A.

Crashlytics generates the following crash log:

```
0   libswiftCore.dylib specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt) -> () + 44
1   CameraLayerView.swift line 20 CameraLayerView.init(coder : NSCoder) -> CameraLayerView?
2   CameraLayerView.swift line 0 @objc CameraLayerView.init(coder : NSCoder) -> CameraLayerView?
3   UIKit -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 248
32  UIKit UIApplicationMain + 208
33  AppDelegate.swift line 17 main
34  libdispatch.dylib (Missing)
```

I've checked line#20 in CameraLayerView but it is just an initialization statement

```
private let ciContext = CIContext(EAGLContext: EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2))
```

Mentioned below is the CameraLayerView file. Any help would be appreciated

```
var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var sessionOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

private var pixelBuffer : CVImageBuffer!
private var attachments : CFDictionary!
private var ciImage : CIImage!
private let ciContext = CIContext(EAGLContext: EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2))
private var imageOptions : [String : AnyObject]!

var faceFound = false
var image : UIImage!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height/2)
    previewLayer.bounds = self.frame
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
}

func loadCamera() {
    let camera = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    for device in camera {
        if device.position == .Front {
            do{
                for input in captureSession.inputs {
                    captureSession.removeInput(input as! AVCaptureInput)
                }
                for output in captureSession.outputs {
                    captureSession.removeOutput(output as! AVCaptureOutput)
                }
                previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                previewLayer.session = nil
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    sessionOutput.videoSettings = [String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey) : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
                    sessionOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.rawValue), 0))
                    sessionOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput) {
                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
                        captureSession.startRunning()

                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue {
                        case 1:
                            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                            break
                        case 2:
                            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
                            break
                        case 3:
                            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
                            break
                        case 4:
                            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeLeft
                            break
                        default:
                            break
                        }
                        self.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
}

func takePicture() -> UIImage {
    self.previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    self.captureSession.stopRunning()
    return image
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)
    ciImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!, options: attachments as? [String : AnyObject])
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .PortraitUpsideDown {
        imageOptions = [CIDetectorImageOrientation : 8]
    } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeLeft {
        imageOptions = [CIDetectorImageOrientation : 3]
    } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeRight {
        imageOptions = [CIDetectorImageOrientation : 1]
    } else {
        imageOptions = [CIDetectorImageOrientation : 6]
    }
    let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: ciContext, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])
    let features = faceDetector.featuresInImage(ciImage, options: imageOptions)
    if features.count == 0 {
        if faceFound == true {
            faceFound = false
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
            }
        }
    } else {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .PortraitUpsideDown {
            image = UIImage(CGImage: ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, fromRect: ciImage.extent), scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Left)
        } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeLeft {
            image = UIImage(CGImage: ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, fromRect: ciImage.extent), scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Down)
        } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeRight {
            image = UIImage(CGImage: ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, fromRect: ciImage.extent), scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Up)
        } else {
            image = UIImage(CGImage: ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, fromRect: ciImage.extent), scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)
        }
        if faceFound == false {
            faceFound = true
            for feature in features {
                if feature.isKindOfClass(CIFaceFeature) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash locally (in Xcode), or only on the user's devices? If so, what does the console log say?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the error myself. Neither have I been able to find a pattern for the chain of events that lead to this crash. It doesn't happen that often but when it does happen, it forces the app to restart (which is a weird behaviour in and of itself since an app crash would general just crash the app instead of restarting it)

Comment: I have never heard of an iOS app "crashing and restarting automatically" (other than the system "app" Springboard).

Comment: It is a weird behaviour. Generally it only happens when you change privacy settings (in which case the OS forces the app to restart in order for the new settings to take effect). Anyways, thanks for taking interest. Hopefully, someone out there will have an idea.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of help; haven't used Core Image in years, and back then only so much. Fixing a crash you can't reproduce locally is very challenging; Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested a theory and it worked. Since ciContext was being initialised with view initialisation, it seemed like the app was crashing due to a race condition. I moved the initialisation for ciContext into my loadCamera method and it hasn't crashed since.

**UPDATE**

Another thing I noticed was that, in various tutorials and blog posts on the internet, the statement `let ciContext = CIContext(EAGLContext: EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2))` was declared in two seperate statements such that it became

```
let eaglContext = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2)
let ciContext = CIContext(EAGLContext: eaglContext)
```

I still don't what exactly was causing the app to crash in the first place but these two changes seemed to have fix the problem

**CORRECT ANSWER**

Finally found the culprit. In my viewController that used ciContext, I had a timer that was not being invalidated hence keeping a strong reference to the viewController. On every subsequent visit, it would create a new viewController while the previous one was never released from memory. This resulted in the memory filling up overtime. Once it passed a certain threshold, the ciContext intialiser would return nil because of low memory which would in turn crash the app.